# Ubuntu 20.04.5 New Home WIFI Router connects but doesn't work

Tags: wireless

I recently switched my home router. Following the switch all the other devices in my house work perfectly. My ubuntu computer connects to the network but after that won't do anything. It's as if there is a block on computer from accessing data through the network.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add to your question the output of `ifconfig` so we can have a better look at your interface connected to your network.

Comment: Hi, I don't have ifconfig installed, and elsewhere on askubuntu people have said it's out of date. I have Ip installed

Comment: ifconfig is really old and a newer version was released, that was ip, yes; but ifconfig is still great and performs as well as ip for printing basic info. Actually, issuing `ip address` prints my local ip for my ethernet interface, which happens to be 192.168.1.205/24. And that is wrong, since that IP is for a client and not a network as the "/24" indicates, my network is 192.168.1.0/24. As you have that tool, please provide the output of `ip address`

Comment: Here's the output from ip address. : https://pastebin.com/2nSzJSxs

Sometimes it connects, but has a very slow connection (despite other devices connecting well) other times it will connect but do nothing, other times, it won't connect at all.